# Two way Binding in a custom directive without using NgModel. Possible?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am implementing a dropdown for which I am writing my own directive. I am not using any kind of input element hence not using ngModel. Is two way binding possible with custom attributes?

```js
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', []);

mainApp.directive('tableDropdown', ['$timeout',
  function($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      scope: {
        selectedFilter: '=?'
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        $timeout(function() {
          angular.element(elem).find('li:first-child').addClass(angular.element(elem).find('li').hasClass('selected') ? '' : 'selected');
          scope.selectedFilter.cycleStatus = null;
          angular.element(elem).find('li').click(function(e) {
              if (angular.element(this).closest('ul').hasClass('active')) {
                angular.element(this).closest('ul').removeClass('active');
                scope.selectedFilter.selected = angular.element(this).attr('value');
              } else {
                angular.element(this).closest('ul').addClass('active');
                scope.selectedFilter.selected = null;
              }
              angular.element(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
            })
        }, 0);
      }
    }
  }
])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<th ng-app="mainApp" ng-init="datefilter.selected=null">
  --{{datefilter.selected}}
  <ul class="tableDropdown" selected-filter="datefilter.selected">
    <li value="null" class="default"><span>Cycle Status</span>
    </li>
    <li value="completed"><span>Completed</span>
    </li>
    <li value="cancelled"><span>Cancelled</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</th>
```

Please note I did not add the CSS which makes it look like a dropdown. I didn't think it was necessary.

I want to get the selected value in `datefilter.selected` and then use it to do something else. Is that even possible? If not are there any workaround?

Comment: Yes, two way binding is very much possible, what are you trying to achieve here , on click of any of the values, should the datefilter.selected change ?, because the current code does not seem to do anything like that

Comment: Yes I want it to change the value. I have updated the code from `scope.selectedFilter.cycleStatus` to `scope.selectedFilter.selected`

Comment: As a side note, restricting a directive to a class is generally frowned upon.

Comment: As a side code, this code is not angular: element(this), lots of find, dependency on jquery, not supporting dynamic elements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being, disregarding your code to setup the classes, you can use the below code to change `datefilter.selected.cycleStatus` from inside the `directive` and it would reflect in the UI.

UI:

```
--{{datefilter.selected.cycleStatus}}
  <ul class="tableDropdown" selected-filter="datefilter.selected">
    <li value="null" class="default"><span>Cycle Status</span>
    </li>
    <li value="completed"><span>Completed</span>
    </li>
    <li value="cancelled"><span>Cancelled</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Code:

```
scope: {
    selectedFilter: '='
  },
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

        $timeout(function() {
          scope.selectedFilter.cycleStatus = null;
          elem.find('li').click( 
            function(e) {
              scope.selectedFilter.cycleStatus =angular.element(this).attr('value');
              scope.$apply();
            });


        }, 0);
      }
```

Note the `scope.$apply()` , which is responsible for changing the value in the UI automatically (otherwise it might reflect late after some other element forces the digest cycle)

Here is an example fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5503/

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot. It didn't occur to be to use `scope.$apply();`. I used to think it is required if you are writing async functions like `setTimeout`. Why is it required here?

Comment: It is required when you change values outside of angular, here you are changing scope variable from inside jquery click function, so you need to use apply()